# SQL Where Only In

Tags: sql

I've got a list of about 200,000 plus records divided up by sub-product line which then rolls up to a product line.

For example:

[image]

(BTW, how do I actually show a table in my question?)

What I want is a where statement which will only include results that have ONLY Cable and/or Telephone in their Product Line. So for example, CT-23415 has both Laptops and Cable so it would be excluded from these results b/c while it has Telephone, it also has Laptops and I only want to see results with either Telephone, Cable, or a combination of the two. CT-12345 and CT-41567 then would be the only rows included.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like doing these with aggregation and `having` because this is very general.

In your case:

```
select contract
from list
group by contract
having sum(case when ProductLine not in ('Cable', 'Telephone') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

That is, it counts the number of unacceptable product lines in the contract.  If the number is 0, then all are acceptable and it returns the contract.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
from    YourTable yt1
where   ProductLine in ('Cable', 'Telephone')
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.Contract = yt2.Contract
                and yt2.ProductLine not in ('Cable', 'Telephone')
        )
```